# PostgreSQL delete-statement using big/long-sub-query hangs/fails

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, subquery, psycopg2, sql-delete

I am currently trying to delete about 1+ million rows in a table (actually, 30+ million, but i have made a sub-set, due to problems arising in this as well), where the condition is that the row must not have any references in other tables as a foreign key.. and i delete in batches of 30000 rows at a time.

so the query looks like:

```
DELETE FROM table_name tn WHERE tn.id IN (
    SELECT tn2.id FROM table_name as tn2 
    LEFT JOIN table_name_join_1 ON table_name_join_1.table_id = tn2.id
    LEFT JOIN table_name_join_2 ON table_name_join_2.table_id = tn2.id
    ...
    LEFT JOIN table_name_join_19 ON table_name_join_19.table_id = tn2.id

    WHERE table_name_join_1.table_id IS NULL
    AND table_name_join_2.table_id IS NULL
    ...
    AND table_name_join_19.table_id IS NULL
    LIMIT 30000 OFFSET x
)
```

The table is referenced in 19 different tables, so a lot of left joins in the sub-query, and takes 61 seconds to run without `LIMIT` & `OFFSET` when counting the total amount of rows that will be affected.

**The problem is that the query just hangs**, when doing it in the delete statement, but works when just counting using `COUNT(1)`.. I am not sure if there is a better way of deleting a lot of rows in a table.. or is it a matter of examining the tables referencing the table-in-question and see if some indexes are wack in some way.

Hope someone can help :D Its quite annoying seeing a query work and then just hang/fail straight afterwards when used as a sub-query.

I use psycopg2 on Python 2.7.17 (a work thing).. i also speculated in when to close the cursor from the psycopg2 connection to up speeds.. currently i create the cursor outside the loop running the delete, and close it along with the db-connection when the script is done... prev. the cursor was closed after each commit of a delete-statement, but it seemed a bit to much to me.. i don't know? Current loop looks like:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
while count >= offset:
   ...
   delete(cursor, batch_size, offset)
   ...
   offset += batch_size
```

Also, is it a bad idea to `commit()` after each delete-statement is executed or should i wait until after the loop is finished executing all the delete statements, and then commit.. if so, shouldn't i look into using transactions instead ?

Basically I hope someone can tell me why stuff is so slow/fails, even though a count without limit and offset "only" takes 60 seconds??

Comment: `The table is referenced in 19 different tables, ` Please show us the complete query, instead of `...` ( and the answer is probably: `NOT EXISTS(...)` )

Comment: I have added more of the LEFT JOINs, but they are the same just on different tables (where `table_id` is a foreign key to `table_name`), which was why i didnt write them all.. Essentially it was just to show that i have a big sub-query which returns 30000 ID's (in 1 batch) the DELETE-query then have to run against.. how would you use NOT EXIST, now i am curious :) ? I can't see how I would, since i don't have all the 1+ million IDs.. since the delete is done in batches. But i am game on trying everything, almost, out :-)

Comment: Irrelevant detail: you do not need the offset. After the first batch, the records will have been deleted, and the first record to delete in the next batch would be **1**. Second detail: you do not need to include `table_name` in the subquery, you can instead use the outer `table_name tn`. (this is where the EXISTS() enters the picture) Also: do you have supporting indexes for the FKs? (check the query plan!)

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE FROM xxx` has almost the same subsyntax as `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxx` ; so just to test the plan, you can run the fragment below, and check if you get an indexed plan:

---

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table_name tn 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
    FROM  table_name_join_1 x1 WHERE  x1.table_id = tn.id
        )
        --
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
    FROM  table_name_join_2 x2 WHERE  x2.table_id = tn.id
        )
        --
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
    FROM  table_name_join_3 x3 WHERE  x3.table_id = tn.id
        )
        --
        -- et cetera
        --
        ;
```

---

Create some data, since it is hard to benchmark pseudocode:

---

```
SELECT version();

CREATE TABLE table_name
        ( id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , name text
        );

INSERT INTO table_name ( name )
SELECT 'Name_' || gs::text
FROM generate_series(1,100000) gs;
        --
CREATE TABLE table_name_join_2
        ( id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , table_id INTEGER REFERENCES table_name(id)
        , name text
        );
INSERT INTO table_name_join_2(table_id,name)
SELECT src.id , 'Name_' || src.id :: text
FROM table_name src
WHERE src.id % 2 = 0
        ;
        --
CREATE TABLE table_name_join_3
        ( id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , table_id INTEGER REFERENCES table_name(id)
        , name text
        );
INSERT INTO table_name_join_3(table_id,name)
SELECT src.id , 'Name_' || src.id :: text
FROM table_name src
WHERE src.id % 3 = 0
        ;
        --
CREATE TABLE table_name_join_5
        ( id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , table_id INTEGER REFERENCES table_name(id)
        , name text
        );
INSERT INTO table_name_join_5(table_id,name)
SELECT src.id , 'Name_' || src.id :: text
FROM table_name src
WHERE src.id % 5 = 0
        ;
        --
CREATE TABLE table_name_join_7
        ( id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , table_id INTEGER REFERENCES table_name(id)
        , name text
        );
INSERT INTO table_name_join_7(table_id,name)
SELECT src.id , 'Name_' || src.id :: text
FROM table_name src
WHERE src.id % 7 = 0
        ;
        --
CREATE TABLE table_name_join_11
        ( id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , table_id INTEGER REFERENCES table_name(id)
        , name text
        );
INSERT INTO table_name_join_11(table_id,name)
SELECT src.id , 'Name_' || src.id :: text
FROM table_name src
WHERE src.id % 11 = 0
        ;
```

---

Now, run the DELETE query:

---

```
VACUUM ANALYZE table_name;
VACUUM ANALYZE table_name_join_2;
VACUUM ANALYZE table_name_join_3;
VACUUM ANALYZE table_name_join_5;
VACUUM ANALYZE table_name_join_7;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
DELETE
FROM table_name tn
WHERE 1=1
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM  table_name_join_2 x2 WHERE  x2.table_id = tn.id)
        --
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM  table_name_join_3 x3 WHERE  x3.table_id = tn.id)
        --
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM  table_name_join_5 x5 WHERE  x5.table_id = tn.id)
        --
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM  table_name_join_7 x7 WHERE  x7.table_id = tn.id)
        --
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM  table_name_join_11 x11 WHERE  x11.table_id = tn.id)
        --
        -- et cetera
        --
        ;
SELECT count(*) FROM table_name;
```

---

Now, exactly the same, but with supporting indexes on the FKs:

---

```
CREATE INDEX table_name_join_2_2 ON table_name_join_2( table_id);
CREATE INDEX table_name_join_3_3 ON table_name_join_3( table_id);
CREATE INDEX table_name_join_5_5 ON table_name_join_5( table_id);
CREATE INDEX table_name_join_7_7 ON table_name_join_7( table_id);
CREATE INDEX table_name_join_11_11 ON table_name_join_11( table_id);

VACUUM ANALYZE table_name;
VACUUM ANALYZE table_name_join_2;
VACUUM ANALYZE table_name_join_3;
VACUUM ANALYZE table_name_join_5;
VACUUM ANALYZE table_name_join_7;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
DELETE
FROM table_name tn
WHERE 1=1
    ...
    ;


----------

Query plan#1:

----------

DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
                                                 version
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.6 on armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf, compiled by gcc (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) 8.3.0, 32-bit
(1 row)

CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 100000
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 50000
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 33333
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 20000
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 14285
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 9090
SET
SET
VACUUM
VACUUM
VACUUM
VACUUM
VACUUM                                                                                    QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Delete on table_name tn  (cost=3969.52..7651.94 rows=11429 width=36) (actual time=812.010..812.011 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Hash Anti Join  (cost=3969.52..7651.94 rows=11429 width=36) (actual time=206.775..712.982 rows=20779 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (tn.id = x7.table_id)
         ->  Hash Anti Join  (cost=3557.10..7088.09 rows=13334 width=34) (actual time=183.070..654.030 rows=24242 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (tn.id = x5.table_id)
               ->  Hash Anti Join  (cost=2979.10..6329.25 rows=16667 width=28) (actual time=149.870..578.173 rows=30303 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: (tn.id = x3.table_id)
                     ->  Hash Anti Join  (cost=2016.11..5124.59 rows=25000 width=22) (actual time=95.589..461.053 rows=45455 loops=1)
                           Hash Cond: (tn.id = x2.table_id)
                           ->  Merge Anti Join  (cost=572.11..3271.21 rows=50000 width=16) (actual time=14.486..261.955 rows=90910 loops=1)
                                 Merge Cond: (tn.id = x11.table_id)
                                 ->  Index Scan using table_name_pkey on table_name tn  (cost=0.29..2344.99 rows=100000 width=10) (actual time=0.031..118.968 rows=100000 loops=1)
                                 ->  Sort  (cost=571.82..589.22 rows=6960 width=10) (actual time=14.446..20.365 rows=9090 loops=1)
                                       Sort Key: x11.table_id
                                       Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 612kB
                                       ->  Seq Scan on table_name_join_11 x11  (cost=0.00..127.60 rows=6960 width=10) (actual time=0.029..6.939 rows=9090 loops=1)
                           ->  Hash  (cost=819.00..819.00 rows=50000 width=10) (actual time=80.439..80.440 rows=50000 loops=1)
                                 Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2014kB
                                 ->  Seq Scan on table_name_join_2 x2  (cost=0.00..819.00 rows=50000 width=10) (actual time=0.019..36.848 rows=50000 loops=1)
                     ->  Hash  (cost=546.33..546.33 rows=33333 width=10) (actual time=53.678..53.678 rows=33333 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1428kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on table_name_join_3 x3  (cost=0.00..546.33 rows=33333 width=10) (actual time=0.027..24.132 rows=33333 loops=1)
               ->  Hash  (cost=328.00..328.00 rows=20000 width=10) (actual time=32.884..32.885 rows=20000 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 32768  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 832kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on table_name_join_5 x5  (cost=0.00..328.00 rows=20000 width=10) (actual time=0.017..15.135 rows=20000 loops=1)
         ->  Hash  (cost=233.85..233.85 rows=14285 width=10) (actual time=23.542..23.542 rows=14285 loops=1)
               Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 567kB
               ->  Seq Scan on table_name_join_7 x7  (cost=0.00..233.85 rows=14285 width=10) (actual time=0.016..10.742 rows=14285 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 4.470 ms
 Trigger for constraint table_name_join_2_table_id_fkey: time=172949.350 calls=20779
 Trigger for constraint table_name_join_3_table_id_fkey: time=116772.757 calls=20779
 Trigger for constraint table_name_join_5_table_id_fkey: time=71218.348 calls=20779
 Trigger for constraint table_name_join_7_table_id_fkey: time=51760.503 calls=20779
 Trigger for constraint table_name_join_11_table_id_fkey: time=36120.128 calls=20779
 Execution Time: 449783.490 ms
(35 rows)

 count
-------
 79221
(1 row)
```

---

Query plan#2:

---

```
SET
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
SET
VACUUM
VACUUM
VACUUM
VACUUM
VACUUM
                                                                                         QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Delete on table_name tn  (cost=1.73..6762.95 rows=11429 width=36) (actual time=776.987..776.988 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Merge Anti Join  (cost=1.73..6762.95 rows=11429 width=36) (actual time=0.212..676.794 rows=20779 loops=1)
         Merge Cond: (tn.id = x7.table_id)
         ->  Merge Anti Join  (cost=1.44..6322.99 rows=13334 width=34) (actual time=0.191..621.986 rows=24242 loops=1)
               Merge Cond: (tn.id = x5.table_id)
               ->  Merge Anti Join  (cost=1.16..5706.94 rows=16667 width=28) (actual time=0.172..550.669 rows=30303 loops=1)
                     Merge Cond: (tn.id = x3.table_id)
                     ->  Merge Anti Join  (cost=0.87..4661.02 rows=25000 width=22) (actual time=0.147..438.036 rows=45455 loops=1)
                           Merge Cond: (tn.id = x2.table_id)
                           ->  Merge Anti Join  (cost=0.58..2938.75 rows=50000 width=16) (actual time=0.125..250.082 rows=90910 loops=1)
                                 Merge Cond: (tn.id = x11.table_id)
                                 ->  Index Scan using table_name_pkey on table_name tn  (cost=0.29..2344.99 rows=100000 width=10) (actual time=0.031..116.630 rows=100000 loops=1)
                                 ->  Index Scan using table_name_join_11_11 on table_name_join_11 x11  (cost=0.29..230.14 rows=9090 width=10) (actual time=0.090..11.228 rows=9090 loops=1)
                           ->  Index Scan using table_name_join_2_2 on table_name_join_2 x2  (cost=0.29..1222.29 rows=50000 width=10) (actual time=0.019..59.500 rows=50000 loops=1)
                     ->  Index Scan using table_name_join_3_3 on table_name_join_3 x3  (cost=0.29..816.78 rows=33333 width=10) (actual time=0.022..40.473 rows=33333 loops=1)
               ->  Index Scan using table_name_join_5_5 on table_name_join_5 x5  (cost=0.29..491.09 rows=20000 width=10) (actual time=0.016..23.105 rows=20000 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using table_name_join_7_7 on table_name_join_7 x7  (cost=0.29..351.86 rows=14285 width=10) (actual time=0.017..16.903 rows=14285 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 4.737 ms
 Trigger for constraint table_name_join_2_table_id_fkey: time=1114.497 calls=20779
 Trigger for constraint table_name_join_3_table_id_fkey: time=1096.065 calls=20779
 Trigger for constraint table_name_join_5_table_id_fkey: time=1094.951 calls=20779
 Trigger for constraint table_name_join_7_table_id_fkey: time=1090.509 calls=20779
 Trigger for constraint table_name_join_11_table_id_fkey: time=1173.987 calls=20779
 Execution Time: 6426.626 ms
(24 rows)

 count
-------
 79221
(1 row)
```

---

So, the query speeds up from 450 seconds to 7 seconds. And most of the time appears to be spent on checking the FK constraints, *after* the actual delete in the base table. [these constraints are implemented as *invisible* triggers in Postgres]

---

Summary table:

---

```
 query type     | indexes on all 5 FKs  |       workmem |       total time(ms)  | time for triggers
----------------+-----------------------+---------------+-----------------------+-------------------
NOT EXISTS()    | No                    | 4Mb           |       449783.490      |     448821.083
NOT EXISTS()    | Yes                   | 4Mb           |         6426.626      |       5570.009
NOT EXISTS()    | Yes                   | 64Kb          |         6405.273      |       5545.352
NOT IN()        | No                    | 4Mb           |       449435.530      |     448829.179
NOT IN()        | Yes                   | 4Mb           |         6113.690      |       5443.505
NOT IN()        | Yes                   | 64Kb          |      8595341.467      |       5545.796
```

---

Conclusion: it is up to you to decide if you want indexes on Foreign Keys.

Comment: I tried out this concept, but since making sub-queries is slower than left joins, i couldn't really use this. The focus of the task i am working on have also changed from the script having to delete rows fast, to just delete rows one-by-one, which then makes it a 100 times easier to check foreign-key constraints.

But i think a lot of the issues here is related to missing indexes.. the DB is old, and weird designed. I thank you for your help.. especially with the "irrelevant" part which was not irrelevant, since the OFFSET got the fetch query to get out of range at a certain point.

Comment: **run the fragment below, and check if you get an indexed plan** Did you get an indexed plan?

Comment: i get an `query plan` with 88 rows.. where multiple of them are `Parallel Seq Scan on table_name_*` and not in `Parallel Index Scan..` which might confirm my suspicion that our DB is really bad indexed.

Comment: `... but since making sub-queries is slower than left joins ...` You are misinformed.

Comment: well i tested it as well, and they where way slower for me.. but if you have some doc telling me why sub-queries are faster than JOINs i would gladly read it.. but the different stuff i read, and my tests, says otherwise.

Comment: But the scope of my task have changed.. so i will not be doing anything of this anymore, so its kinda pointless to continue, since i will not be testing it anymore... how do i close this issue here on stack?

Comment: `well i tested it as well, and they where way slower for me` Did you add the indexes for the FKs? Did you check the resulting plans? Did you even check *my* query plans?

Comment: there is an index problem in general in our DB, and i can't just modify it atm.. the explain hinted at, that only seq scans where performed. And since my task focus is removing rows not being used (while not modifying the DB), we have decided to go through rows one-by-one.. and we have a sub task about fixing indexes. But again, if you have some official documentation that tells sub-queries are faster JOINs, i would love to read up on it.. but currently i found this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rewriting-subqueries.html which says the opposite.. given that is mysql and not postgres

Comment: `subqueries are slow`  is a myth spread by mysql. Postgres is *really* different. Read the documentation from postgres, and learn to understand the plans and the planner. And: you **really need the indexes** it is only an hour of work Performing *row at a time* operations is basically an `O(n*n)` operation. A batch update is O(n*log(n)) or better, given proper indexing.